# Why number of partitions after join are different in Spark Streaming

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

```
val sparkConf = new SparkConf()
val streamingContext = new StreamingContext(sparkConf, Minutes(1))

var historyRdd: RDD[(String, ArrayList[String])] = streamingContext.sparkContext.emptyRDD

var historyRdd_2: RDD[(String, ArrayList[String])] = streamingContext.sparkContext.emptyRDD


val stream_1 = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, GenericData.Record, StringDecoder, GenericDataRecordDecoder](streamingContext, kafkaParams ,  Set(inputTopic_1))
val dstream_2 = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream[String, GenericData.Record, StringDecoder, GenericDataRecordDecoder](streamingContext, kafkaParams ,  Set(inputTopic_2))


val dstream_2 = stream_2.map((r: Tuple2[String, GenericData.Record]) => 
{
  //some mapping
}

val historyDStream = dstream_1.transform(rdd => rdd.union(historyRdd))
val historyDStream_2 = dstream_2.transform(rdd => rdd.union(historyRdd_2))
val fullJoinResult = historyDStream.fullOuterJoin(historyDStream_2)

 val filtered = fullJoinResult.filter(r => r._2._1.isEmpty)


filtered.foreachRDD{rdd =>

  val formatted = rdd.map(r  => (r._1 , r._2._2.get)) 

  historyRdd_2.unpersist(false) // unpersist the 'old' history RDD
  historyRdd_2 = formatted // assign the new history
  historyRdd_2.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK) // cache the computation
}


val filteredStream = fullJoinResult.filter(r => r._2._2.isEmpty)


filteredStream.foreachRDD{rdd =>
  val formatted = rdd.map(r => (r._1 , r._2._1.get)) 
  historyRdd.unpersist(false) // unpersist the 'old' history RDD
  historyRdd = formatted // assign the new history
  historyRdd.persist(StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK) // cache the computation
}
streamingContext.start()
streamingContext.awaitTermination()
  }
}
```

DStream_1 and DStream_2 has 128 partitions each but after performing the join the resultant DStream has 3 partitions , I haven't done any repartition. I had this thought that if no. of partitions of DStream are same then the join resultant DStream has same number of partitions as join happens partition to partition.Please correct me if I am wrong in that case.

Comment: How is the distribution of the keys in your data?